# php xpath - get node position

Tags: php

I have the following stripped down php code...

```
foreach ($xpath->query('/html/body//a')} as $queryitem) {
   $nodeposition = ???;
   $parentposition = ???;
}
```

...from this is it possible to find the position of each node and the position its parent?

for example:

`0..<html>`
`1....<head>`
`2......<title>`
`3......<meta>`
`4......<meta>`
`5....<body>`
`6......<div>`
`7........<a>`

This would produce a kind-of ID for each tag and the ID of the parent tag which it joins to.

So the results would be = 0|,1|0,2|1,3|1,4|1,5|0,6|5,7|6

Comment: What do you mean by position? The position of the node in the tree?

Comment: yes, so I can reconstruct parts of it later from a database

Comment: What would the parent's position be? The position in a result set for //* in document order? <http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#dt-document-order>

Comment: I've added an example to the post. I know there is a position() function for xpath but of course this doesn't work in php's domxpath so I'm looking for another solution. I'm really hoping i don't have to iterate and count through every single node...

Comment: What do you need that position for?

Answer (score 2):

If by "position" you mean the count of preceding nodes (as you seem to imply in your sample), then this would work (probably not at top-notch efficiency, but nevertheless):

```
foreach ($xpath->query('/html/body//a') as $queryitem) {
   $nodeposition = count($xpath->query('preceding::*', $queryitem));

   $parent = $xpath->query('parent::*', $queryitem);
   if ($parent->length == 1)
     $parentposition = count($xpath->query('preceding::*', $parent->item(0)));
   else
     $parentposition = -1; // or whatever
}
```

Not tested, but you get the idea.

An alternative would be to code up an XSLT identity transform that adds the position to all nodes in the document as an attribute. You could then read the attribute in you PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to get the position (read xpath) within the dom unless you do some fancy coding yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of the full DOM tree to solve this problem. But with XPath you just get certain subtrees that match the path. You would need to walk the tree up one by one and retrieve the information for every element matched by the XPath. But that might be inefficient. It would probably be better if you walk the tree from the root down and count the number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way of dealing with XML in PHP is using the [SimpleXML](http://nl2.php.net/simplexml) class and loop using the Children attribute. See http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-children.php